# How does Android know that it has to direct allowed vpn application to tun0

Tags: android, vpn, openvpn, android-vpn-service

This is an internal Android question.

I would like to have a clear understanding on what happens when vpn tunnel is established with only specific apps allowed through it using "`builder.addallowedapplication()` " method.

This is similar to how you select apps to process through `openvpn`.

How does it say to `tun0` that these should go through you? What kind of rules does it change or what kind of function calls or api calls it makes in the process.

Kindly help me here.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is based on policy routing. The Linux kernel can work with multiple routing tables and rules that define for which traffic a specific routing table is used. You can see these rules with `ip rule` if `iproute2` is available on your system. The routes in a specific table can be listed with `ip route list table <nr/name>` (use `all` as name to see routes in all tables).

The rules can match different properties associated with a network packet (or a combination of them), e.g. the IP addresses, in-/outbound interfaces, Netfilter marks, or processes' UIDs. The latter in particular is used to exclude/include specific applications. Every app is run by a unique user with its own UID. This allows controlling whether a particular app uses the routing table that directs traffic to the TUN device or not.

For example, using the VPN exclusively for three apps adds rules with these selectors:

```
... uidrange 10010-10010 lookup 1049 
... uidrange 10062-10062 lookup 1049 
... uidrange 10094-10094 lookup 1049
```

Routing table 1049 (this changes for each new VPN instance) contains the route that directs traffic to the TUN device.

On the other hand, if the same three apps are excluded from the VPN the selectors are:

```
... uidrange 0-10009 ...
... uidrange 10011-10061 ...
... uidrange 10063-10093 ...
... uidrange 10095-99999 ...
```

As you can see, traffic from all UIDs (in the range 0-99999) except the three previously seen are directed to the routing table for the TUN device.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. How can i find such rules or routing tables for a vpn instance?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: So, lets assume I have a VPN instance running on my android device and have selected three applications. Where can i find the rules you mentioned like this `... uidrange 10010-10010 lookup 1049` . What is command or file to find the rules. @ecdsa

Comment: Found it. `ip rule show` gave me the result I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, I have a question to ask. I compiled zerotier-one cli myself and it works on rooted Android. But there is a problem with the routing table. `10.0.1.0/24` is zt's virtual network segment, `ip route show` returns `10.0.1.0/24 dev ztyvvzal2p proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.68`, when I access other devices directly on Android via zt's ip I'm able to access other devices directly from eth0, but when I specify the NIC to access (e.g. `ping -I ztyvvzal2p 10.0.1.199`), it is possible to communicate normally.